Spark SQL 3.4 named parameter substitution in Java
Since Spark 3.4, SparkSession.sql(...) supports the use of named parameters in SQL queries:
public Dataset<Row> sql(String sqlText, Map<String,Object> args)
Executes a SQL query substituting named parameters by the given arguments

Unfortunately, the Javadoc is silent about how to specify the named parameters in the SQL query, and in other documentation, a variety of different forms can be found, e.g.

In the pyspark API reference: {param}
In the Spark SQL reference docs: :param
In answers to similar SO questions, and in other sources: ${param}

However, none of these work for me, even though spark.sql.variable.substitute is set to true in my context:
//These throw syntax exceptions because the parameter is not substituted
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM {table}",  Map.of("table",    "my_table"));
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM {table}",  Map.of("{table}",  "my_table"));
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM :table",   Map.of("table",    "my_table"));
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM :table",   Map.of(":table",   "my_table"));
//These replace the parameter with an empty string
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM ${table}", Map.of("table",    "my_table"));
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM ${table}", Map.of("${table}", "my_table"));

The ${param} form looks slightly more promising than the rest, because at least something happens to the query string.
So, long story short: What is the definitive correct form for named parameters, and how do I pass the values for them?

The python api usage is not the same as the scala/java one.
In the links you provide you are shown the identifier function:
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER(:mytab)", args = Map("mytab" -> "`default`.`tab1`")).show()

your code samples aren't however using the identifier function.
The ${var} syntax is for use with SET, not the .sql function.

Oh, silly me, so close and still so far... I thought the IDENTIFIER(...) bit was just to be able to do string operations on identifiers in SQL in general. I didn't connect it to parameter expansion per se.
